# How to add multimedia attachments using ChatKit on Android?

Tags: android, chatkit

I'm using [Influence](https://github.com/ChronosXYZ/Influence) to implement XMPP-based chat in an app. So far, no issue with sending & receiving text messages. The problem is how to enable multimedia attachments? Influence used [ChatKit](https://github.com/stfalcon-studio/ChatKit), and [the docs](https://github.com/stfalcon-studio/ChatKit/blob/master/docs/COMPONENT_MESSAGE_INPUT.MD) stated this:

> If you want to add multimedia messages, you may need an "attachments"
> button. You can enable it with the attribute
> showAttachmentButton="true"

Already done (see [activity_chat.xml](https://github.com/ChronosXYZ/Influence/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_chat.xml)):

```
   <com.stfalcon.chatkit.messages.MessageInput
        android:id="@+id/message_input"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:inputHint="@string/hint_enter_a_message"
        app:showAttachmentButton="true"/>
```

And this is my modified ChatFragment (I added the `MessageInput.AttachmentsListener` interface):

```
class ChatActivity : AppCompatActivity(), CoreContracts.IChatViewContract, MessageInput.AttachmentsListener {
    private var messageList: MessagesList? = null
    private var messageInput: MessageInput? = null
    private var chatNameTextView: TextView? = null
    private var chatAvatar: ImageView? = null
    private var userStatus: TextView? = null
    private var presenter: ChatPresenter? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat)

        val intent = intent


        val toolbar = findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar_chat_activity)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        supportActionBar!!.setTitle("")
        supportActionBar!!.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
        supportActionBar!!.setHomeButtonEnabled(true)
        messageList = findViewById<MessagesList>(R.id.messages_list)
        messageList!!.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        chatNameTextView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.appbar_username)
        userStatus = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.user_status_text)
        chatAvatar = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.profile_image_chat_activity)
        messageInput = findViewById<MessageInput>(R.id.message_input)
        messageInput!!.setInputListener {
            presenter!!.sendMessage(it.toString())
        }

        // added by anta40
        messageInput!!.setAttachmentsListener {
            //select attachments
            // how??
        }

        chatNameTextView!!.text = intent.getStringExtra("chatName")
        presenter = ChatPresenter(this, intent.getStringExtra("chatID").toString())
        loadAvatarFromIntent(intent)
        presenter!!.loadLocalMessages()
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when (item.itemId) {
            android.R.id.home -> {
                finish()
                return true
            }
        }
        presenter!!.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        presenter!!.onDestroy()
        presenter = null
    }

    override fun setAdapter(adapter: MessagesListAdapter<GenericMessage>) {
        messageList!!.setAdapter(adapter)
    }

    private fun loadAvatarFromIntent(intent: Intent) {
        val avatarBytes: ByteArray? = intent.getByteArrayExtra("chatAvatar")
        if(avatarBytes != null) {
            val avatar = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(avatarBytes, 0, avatarBytes.size)
            chatAvatar!!.setImageBitmap(avatar)
        } else {
            val chatName = intent.getStringExtra("chatName")
            val firstLetter = Character.toString(chatName!![0].toUpperCase())
            chatAvatar!!.setImageDrawable(
                TextDrawable.builder()
                    .beginConfig()
                    .width(64)
                    .height(64)
                    .endConfig()
                    .buildRound(firstLetter, ColorGenerator.MATERIAL.getColor(firstLetter)))
        }
    }

    override fun setUserStatus(status: String) {
        userStatus!!.text = status
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.chat_activity_menu, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        presenter!!.loadRecentPageMessages()
    }

    override fun getActivityObject(): Activity {
        return this
    }

    override fun showToast(text: String) {
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

    //added by anta40
    override fun onAddAttachments() {
       // presenter!!.getAdapter().addToStart()
    }
}
```

If the app is run, and the "+" (attachment button) is clicked, of course nothing happens. I guess there are missing parts inside `onAddAttachments()` and `setAttachmentsListener()`, and not sure how to fill them correctly.

Any hints/code examples is highly appreciated.